# When can we write an r.v. as a function of another r.v. and an independent randomization?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that we are given two random variables $X,Y$. When can we write X as a function of Y and some independent randomization?

Formally and more generally, suppose that we are given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A}, P)$, and two $\mathcal{A}$-measurable maps $f:\Omega \mapsto \Omega_f$ and $g:\Omega \mapsto \Omega_g$. Under what conditions can we write $f$ as a function of $g$ and some other (measurable) map $h$ independent of $g$? That is, when can we say that there exist $h:\Omega \mapsto \Omega_h$ and $\phi:\Omega_g \times \Omega_h \mapsto \Omega_f$ such that $f(\omega) = \phi(g(\omega), h(\omega))$ and $h^{-1}(\Omega_h)$ is independent of $g^{-1}(\Omega_g)$? Can we say this in general?

Comment: any answers? is the question clear?